# Database synchronization and lost connection

Tags: database, architecture, synchronization, replication

I have to create a way for database replication. The scenario is as follows:

1. I have one master database and a lot of client databases. Sometimes clients works offline with their local databases. When the connection between a client and server is established, they exchange the new records. I used Lamport timestamps to see which records are not synchronized.

The problem came when the connection is lost. For example client send new data to master, master recieves the new data, insert it but cannot send status ok to the client. After that client will send records again, which is not ok. Please help me how to resolve that.

P.S There is one more question in the picture: What if we have a dependent transactions (like block credit card and unblock) and we have block on the master db, but it is missing on the client db. Then  a person go to the office where is the client db and ask to unblock his card. As I said the record that the card is blocked is missing on the client. How to handle the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a transaction, and require that the Client ack the status "OK".  If the client does not ack the "OK", roll back the transaction.